# Laravel installer error message 'failed to open stream: permission denied'

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I keep receiving an error when trying to install Laravel.

I already run cmd as administrator and tried fixing this by un-ticking the folder attributes in properties which says

> "Read-Only (Only applies to files in folder)"

with the hope that the permission is now accessible by Composer. The problem occurs when I run this command line:

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

I still get this error message:

> [ErrorException]
>   file_put_contents(C:\Users\fikri\AppData\Roaming\Composer): failed to
>   open stream: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

if you are windos user, open cmd or git bash with administrator privilege

if you are linux user install with super user privilege

```
sudo composer global require laravel/installer
```

Comment: I already run cmd as administrator I still received the same error.